# How to use console as input and output for Guile Scheme?

Tags: console, scheme, mit-scheme, guile

I understand that Scheme uses ports to perform Input and Output. While trying to learn how to get console input and output, I have come across MIT-Scheme's `console-i/o-port` variable.

But, the guile interpreter says it is an Unbound Variable. I would like to know how we can use ports to get input from and output to the console (Terminal in Unix) in a Guile Scheme Script. I am still a rookie in Scheme and Linux, a clear step-by-step is appreciated.

Also, how does `(display <object>)` work? Does it use ports inherently or is there another way.

P.S. If there is another way without using ports please let me know how to use that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to read and write SExps, in guile you have (read), (write), (display) etc., if you want to read characters only use (read-char) and (write-char) -- they all use the input/output ports resp. you picked, by default they are stdin and stdout. Everything is rather straightforward (https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Input-and-Output.html#Input-and-Output).

You might also be interested in guile-ncurses (https://www.gnu.org/software/guile-ncurses/).

Of some more goodies check out pretty-print module from ice-9 (on very long sexps it's slow but outputs them really nicely formatted, great for e.g. code generation):

```
  (use-modules (ice-9 pretty-print))
  (pretty-print `(super cool stuff (+ 2 3) => ,(+ 2 3)))
```

And if you need your own parser, check out the lalr module (system base lalr).

**edit** a small example which reads a number, multiplies by itself and prints out the result:

```
#!/usr/bin/guile -s
!#

(let ((x (read)))
  (display (* x x))
  (newline))
```

(remember to chmod +x this script).

***edit** changed the expression to let form as Chris suggested, indeed the fewer parentheses the better*

Comment: Could you give me a small script for reading from the terminal and squaring it and printing. I wanted to know if there is an alternative for console-i/o-port in MIT-Scheme?

Comment: @TarunMaganti there you go, does this help you? perhaps you'd like a more elaborate one, but this one works just fine with stdin/out (I was using guile ang gambit a lot piped with other things).

Comment: BTW, `((lambda (x) (* x x)) (read))` is more idiomatically written as `(let ((x (read))) (* x x))`..

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young thank you, it looks better now :)

Answer (score 2):

In guile you have 2 functions: `current-input-port` and `current-output-port` ([the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Default-Ports.html))

to read and put text into string (if you don't want to read s-expressions) you can use this function:

```
(define (read-port port)
    (let iter ((result '()) (chr (read-char port)))
        (if (eof-object? chr)
            (list->string result)
            (iter (append result (list chr)) (read-char port)))))
```

reading from stdin will be:

```
(read-port (current-input-port))
```

to write to stdout you can use `display` it also accept second argument which is port [relevant docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Scheme-Write.html#index-display)

Comment: The link to relevant doc points to the old old documentation.

Comment: @amirouche where can I find new documentation then?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Scheme-Write.html#index-display